# UITableView Row Add Callback not Invoked

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, callback, datasource

I am using my first UITableView and only get some callbacks.  In the code below I want to populate a TableView with test data.  The 2 callbacks that ask for the number of sections and row count work fine.  The callback that allows population of a cell is never invoked.  I have a TableView object on my story board, a prototype cell with identifier "cellReuseIdentifier" and an outlet to the instance variable btListView.  Any guidance would be appretiated.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{
    var tableData: [String] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var btListView:  UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for i in 0...5
        {
            tableData.append("(\(i)")
        }

        btListView.dataSource = self
    }
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = btListView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellReuseIdentifier")! as UITableViewCell

    let temp = tableData[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = temp

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return tableData.count
}
```

Comment: are you sure you have 'tableData' by the time it calls `numberOfRowsInSection ` method. try adding `btListView .reloadData()` at the end of `viewDidLoad ` method after `btListView.dataSource = self` this line

Comment: Yes, there is data.  I added print statements just to be sure.  The reloadData() didn't help.  I created a test app with the same code and a bunch of other stuff removed (text and blue tooth delegates) and that app worked.  I deleted and re-added the table view and proto cell but no go.

Comment: So I just took a look at the differences between the 2 apps and the one that doesn't work has the TableView IN a StackView.  After I move it to the top level of the view (above stack view) the call back is triggered.  I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: How are you setting the constraints on your StackView and TableView? If the tableView ends up with a Height of Zero, no row will ever be shown, and `cellForRowAt` will never be called.

Comment: I didn't change the hight or width but now that you mention it, when the list view is contained in the stack view the list view doesn't show up at all.

Comment: That did it.  The width and height were set to 0.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per above, the simple fix is to ensure a list view has a width and height set via the constraint editor or the add row call back will not be fired.